# Как сделать backspace в Си?

Tags: c

Есть программа. Пользователь в цикле вводит через пробел числа как отрицательные, так и положительные. Для завершения программы в конце пользователь должен вводить ноль. 
Программа выводит все положительные числа последовательности через пробел исключая ноль. 
Вот сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int res = 0;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &res);
        if (res > 0) {
            printf("%d", res);
            printf("");
        }
    } while (res != 0);
    return (0);
}
```

В принципе программа работает правильно, просто преподаватель требует, чтобы программа проходила контрольное тестирование, которое заключается в том, чтобы после последнего введённого числа не ставился пробел.

Comment: А на каком это языке написано? Что все с большой буквы?

Comment: Я с телефона писал вопрос :)

Comment: Ставьте пробел *до* числа :) Кстати, ваша программа не позволяет вводить отрицательные числа - вернее, не выводит их. Измените условие на `if (res != 0)` или просто на `if (res)`.

Comment: @Harry если перед числом ставить, то тоже будет не верно, программа тоже не пройдёт контрольное тестирование. Программа и не должна выводить отрицательные числа, она должна лишь положительные выводить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеется несколько подходов.

Один из них заключается в том, чтобы просто завести дополнительную переменную, которая будет сообщать, было ли выведено уже положительное число перед выводом текущего положительного числа.

Например,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    for ( int x, prev_x = 0; scanf( "%d", &x ) == 1 && x != 0;  )
    {
        if ( x > 0 )
        {
            if ( prev_x ) putchar( ' ' );
            printf( "%d", x );
            prev_x = 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```